# SkyNet3D firmware home settings

Tags: marlin, anet-a8, firmware, skynet3d

I recently installed SkyNet3D V1.1 on my Anet A8 printer. When I prepare the printer and select "auto home" it moves the head close to the upper right hand side of the bed. How do I change these settings so the printer auto homes to the center of the bed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you found and fixed the problem? If so, have the answers below led you to the solution? Please vote to accept an answer (using the tick button next to the answer) so this question is not bumped up once in a while and can be removed from the unanswered question list. You may even add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours! If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

*Please note that Skynet3D is **OBSOLETE**, this was a [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)) from [Marlin Firmware](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/) that was created to support the "odd" displays (due to alternative pin layout) Anet use on their printers and has been completely integrated in Marlin.*

---

Note that homing is used to hit the end stops to determine the positioning of the head. There is no such thing as homing in the center of the bed (apart from the Z-axis). How would the head know where it is just after switching the printer on?

When using the constant:

```
#define Z_SAFE_HOMING
```

the printer is instructed to move the head to (in this case to the middle of the bed):

```
#define Z_SAFE_HOMING_X_POINT (X_BED_SIZE / 2)    // X point for Z homing when homing all axis (G28).
#define Z_SAFE_HOMING_Y_POINT (Y_BED_SIZE / 2)    // Y point for Z homing when homing all axis (G28).
```

after sending the `G28` homing command.

Basically it wil home X and Y, then move to the instructed position (in the example the middle of the bed) and then home Z.